# Why can C# check if a 'var' is null?

Tags: c#, null, nullable, var

I have the following code:

```
List<IMessage> messageList = new List<IMessage>();

foreach(var msg in messageList)
{
    if(msg != null)
    {

    }
}
```

How is it possible to check the `var` *msg* against `null`? What tells the compiler that `var` is an `IMessage` and not an `int` or some other type that isn't nullable?

If you look at the example over at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) they give the implicitly typed variables initial values (whereby the declaration becomes explicit). In my case I do not even give it a value, yet the compiler has no problem with it. How does the compiler know that the `msg` is nullable?

Comment: Your `messageList` is a list of items of type `IMessage` so the compiler can easily infer that actual type of `msg` is `IMessage`. If the compiler could not infer the type, you would not be able to use `var` - e.g. `var msg;` would not be allowed.

Comment: As an aside, comparing a value against `null` is always permissible anyway. The compiler would simply issue a warning if `msg` were an `int`, since the comparison is always `true`, but it would not be disallowed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert When I check `null` against a value type, I get more than a warning. Not sure what you're saying.

Comment: I'm saying that `var i = 5; Console.WriteLine(i != null)` yields [CS0472](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228621). You may have configured your project to issue warnings as errors.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right I did have it configured that way, and that is interesting I did not know that. I knew that checking null against value types was meaningless because they are not nullable, so I guess I just never tried it.

Comment: It isn't meaningless in general: if `bool f<T>(T t) { return t != null; }`, then `Console.WriteLine(f(5))` will compile without warning. Conceptually, everything in C# is an object, so comparing it against `null` should be allowed. The warning is issued because in this particular case, the comparison always has the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler knows that `msg` is nullable because it is statically typed.  The static type is `IMessage`, even though you did not name it.

The reason the compiler substituted `IMessage` for `var` is that it appeared in `foreach (var` *`identifier`* `in` *`collection`* `)` and the `collection` is an expression of a type that implements `IEnumerable<IMessage>`.

Every appearance of `var` will have some type substituted statically.  (It's possible for that to be `dynamic`, but `dynamic` is not a default, it can only apply when it can be inferred under the static type inference rules)  If the static type inference rules can't find a unique type to substitute, then that use of `var` is disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is a very misleading keyword. 

`var` declares a variable with a specific datatype, *without telling the programmer what that type is.*

What you have actually declared is

```
 foreach (IMessage msg in messageList)
```

but you have to work that out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler infers the type for you. On a basic level, when you say:

```
var x = "foo";
```

The compiler sees that the right hand side of the expression is a `string` and assigns `x` that type.

It's no different when the compiler encounters a `foreach` statement. It determines the `IEnumerable` type (`IEnumerable<IMessage>` in your case) and assigns `msg` the type `IMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your `messageList` is of type `List<IMessage>`, therefore, when you do

`foreach (var m in messageList)`

C# automatically know what type of items to expect (the ones contained in your list, in this example `IMessage` objects) and infers that the var will be translated to `IMessage` during compilation time.

The `var` keyword is just syntactic sugar, it's not actually a type. It just makes your life easier (you don't have to write the actual type)

Answer (score 0):

The type of a `var` is *always* known at compile time. Any situation where the type can't be inferred from the syntax would be a compile-time error.

In this case, you are iterating over a typed collection of `IMessage`s, so the compiler knows that the iteration variable is of type `IMessage` and therefore nullable.